# Is it normal that creating one thread per value of a matrices product is slower than just using 1 thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I create one thread per value of the product of 2 matrices, ( so say the first matrix is n x m and the second is m x l then I create a total of n x l threads ) it appears to be much slower than using just 1 thread to compute everything. Is that normal?

Here's the code if it helps :

The class that create the threads :

```
package ex4;

import java.util.*;

public class OneThreadPerValue extends ComputeMethod {

    public Matrix compute(Matrix m1, Matrix m2) {
        int length = m1.get_m();
        int res_n = m1.get_n();
        int res_m = m2.get_m();
        int[] row;
        int[] col;
        int[][] listOfCol = new int[res_m][m2.get_n()]; // we store the values of each column of the second matrix
                                                        // because the get_colonne is in Theta(n)
        for (int x = 0; x < res_m; x++) {
            listOfCol[x] = m2.get_colonne(x);
        }

        Matrix res = new Matrix(res_n, res_m, this);
        List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<Thread>();

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < res_n; i++) {
                row = m1.get_ligne(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < res_m; j++) {
                    col = listOfCol[j];
                    ThreadMatrixV1 thread = new ThreadMatrixV1(res, col, row, i, j, length);
                    threads.add(thread);
                    thread.start();
                }
            }

            for (Thread thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;

    }
}
```

The threads :

```
package ex4;

public class ThreadMatrixV1 extends Thread {
    private Matrix matrix;
    private int[] col; // the column we want to compute 
    private int[] row; // the row we want to compute 
    private int toBeModifiedCol; // the column we want to modify 
    private int toBeModifiedRow; // the row we want to modify 
    private int length; // the length of the column and row to compute 

    public ThreadMatrixV1(Matrix matrix, int[] col, int[] row, int toBeModifiedRow, int toBeModifiedCol, int length) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
        this.toBeModifiedCol = toBeModifiedCol;
        this.toBeModifiedRow = toBeModifiedRow;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int res = Matrix.computeRowCol(this.row, this.col, this.length);
        this.matrix.set(this.toBeModifiedRow, this.toBeModifiedCol, res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. Threads are generally expensive, requiring initializing new memory space, copying relevant data over, and then running them. They're best used for long-running or blocking operations, not for simple math like this.

Even if your matrices are large enough that using a loop is causing performance degradation, it would be better to use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or similar to start tasks which handle multiple elements of the matrices than to use threads directly: Using an `ExecutorService` allows threads to be re-used internally to avoid extra overhead.

Comment: Thank you! This is for an assignment

Answer (score 2):

Threads do not come for free. They are resources owned and managed by the underlying operating system in the end.

In other words: using threads leads to overhead. That overhead only pays off when the threaded operations last (much) longer than that overhead.

When you have to move 2 bottles of beer from the car to your house, it is quicker to just carry them just so, instead of first getting a basket from the house. But when you have 200 bottles to move, it is worth to first look out for a better way than carrying them one by one. Solutions to problems come with a price tag.

That is the essential difference between effective and efficient btw.